# could not determine the shape of object type 'Data' - converting pytorch list to cuda?

Tags: pytorch

I want to convert a list to a format that can be read into a model in CUDA format.

I have this:

```
print(type(train_dataset))
train_dataset = torch.tensor(train_dataset, device='cuda:0')
print(type(train_dataset))
```

The output is:

```
<class 'list'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_pytorch_test_gpu2.py", line 882, in <module>
    train_dataset = torch.tensor(train_dataset, device='cuda:0')
ValueError: could not determine the shape of object type 'Data'
```

Could someone explain how to convert a list to a format for cuda/what is wrong with what I did?

Answer (score 0):

A [`Dataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html) is an object wrapping around your training data and it's main function is to organize the data, the labels, and possibly their augmentations.

On top of `Dataset` one usually uses a [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader): this object collects training samples from the underlying `Dataset` and puts them into tensors representing mini-batches for training.

Your code should look something like this:

```py
# one-time setup of training data
train_dataset = ...  # your code that construct the Dataset
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=4, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

# training loop
for e in range(num_epochs):
  # each epoch represents one pass over all the training samples.
  for (x, y) in train_loader:  # iterate over the data one _batch_ at a time
    # move training tensors, extracted from the Dataset, to GPU
    x = x.to(device)  
    y = y.to(device)
    # rest of your training code here:
    pred = model(x) 
    # ...
```